# How to make one column table two columns?

Tags: sql, t-sql, select

I wish to make a table from one column to two columns. For example I have a path table.I have 4 rows, I wish to split it to two columns like in the PATH2 table.How may I do that? I wish to do this in order to calculate each paths value

```
╔══════╗
║ PATH ║
╠══════╣
║    1 ║
║    2 ║
║    3 ║
║    4 ║
╚══════╝
```

into

```
╔══════╦═══════╗
║ PATH ║ PATH2 ║
╠══════╬═══════╣
║    1 ║     2 ║
║    2 ║     3 ║
║    3 ║     4 ║
╚══════╩═══════╝
```

Comment: You definitely want to split it on some basis. What is that? What's your condition on which you wish to split

Comment: The condition is the first two rows (1,2) will be in the same row in the new table.. And the 2nd and 3rd rows in the first table will be in the 2nd row in the second table. It goes on like that.. I wish to find the paths and assign distance later on to those paths..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/52983/1)

**MS SQL Server 2008 Schema Setup**:

```
create table YourTable
(
  PATH int
)

insert into YourTable values (1),(2),(3),(4)
```

**Query 1**:

```
select T1.PATH,
       Lead.PATH as PATH2
from YourTable as T1
  cross apply (
              select top(1) PATH
              from YourTable as T2
              where T2.PATH > T1.PATH
              order by T2.PATH
              ) as Lead
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/52983/1/0)**:

```
| PATH | PATH2 |
----------------
|    1 |     2 |
|    2 |     3 |
|    3 |     4 |
```

Answer (score 3):

if you are working on `SQL Server 2012`, you can use `LEAD` analytic function.

```
WITH records
AS
(
    SELECT  PATH,
            LEAD(Path) OVER (ORDER BY PATH) Path2
    FROM    TableName
)
SELECT  Path, Path2
FROM    records 
WHERE   Path2 IS NOT NULL
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/094f4/2)

OR if on `SQL SERVER 2005+`

```
WITH records
AS
(
    SELECT  PATH,
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY PATH) rn
    FROM    TableName
)
SELECT  a.Path, b.Path AS Path2
FROM    records a
        INNER JOIN records b
          ON a.rn+1 = b.rn
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/094f4/4)